# Override filename in maven when deploying file

Tags: maven

I generate zip file in maven-assembly-plugin with specific name and want be able to deploy it.
I define $[my-version} property in initialize phase and I successfully get the file, but when deoplying I get the following error:

> [ERROR] 
>   Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) 
>       on project my-project: C:\Users\pr\work\my-project\target\target\my-file-${my-version}.zip not found. 
>       -> [Help 1]

**Code:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>          
        <file>target/my-file-${my-version}.zip</file>
        <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
        <url>${nexus.url}/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>my-file-${my-version}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/deployment.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>          
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is your property "my-version" in <properties> section (pom.xml) ? Maybe set as parameter in command line with -D ? (mvn install -Dmy-version=1.0, for instance)

Comment: Simply remove the configuration for maven-deploy-plugin and remove the lines `finalName`, `appendAssemblyId` from the configuration of maven-assembly-plugin and the deploy will work.

Comment: I don't want to use command line as it part of CI, all configuration must be supplied in files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in order of phases. When calling goal "deploy:deploy-file" directly, the phase "intialization" wasn't processed.
So, one of the ways is to call it explicitly:

> mvn initialize deploy-file